Laravel 11: Validation error not getting displayed, though dd is working, how to fix?
Blade File
   <div>
              <x-input-label for="rising_above_title" :value="__('Rising Above Title')" />
               <x-text-input id="rising_above_title" name="rising_above_title" type="text" class="mt-2.5 block w-full"
                                     autofocus />
               <x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('rising_above_title')" /> 
     </div>

Store Function
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $card = new RisingAbove();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'rising_above_title' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'rising_above_desc' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'rising_above_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,webp|max:1024',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            //dd($validator->errors());
            return redirect()->route('ra.index')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
}

It is working fine with other controllers in the project but with this it is not working.

Have you imported use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; to the top of the controller?

Yes i have imported that

Okay,Are you sure that the blade file you shared are loaded  through route('ra.index') ?

Yes, everything is fine but I am not being able to figure out why is it not working

Okay got it.Can you please share the code for x-input-error?There might be some issue.

I have provided the code in my post

You shared the blade view which consist of x-input-error component. Doesn't it ? So i am asking for how did you pass messages to show errors?

I am using the laravel breeze way of doing things. I created new blade file and controller to make it work
<x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('rising_above_title')" />

this displays the error message. It is working fine for another blade file and controller but i am having problem with this one

I found out the issue. It was the route redirection.
Answer
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

